# Trying to make a line follow a random path

Tags: python, random, codeskulptor

I am trying to make a line follow a random path in Python. I have to use [SimpleGUI](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#tabs-Graphics) to do it. So far I have done enough to make the line follow a random path but after the for loop, the code restarts. I am not that familiar with SimpleGUI, so I am sure there is a good reason for the code restarting but I have no idea how to fix it. I have provided the [code](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user306_WuHu8oH9iIpipaG.py) below, thanks in advance!

```
import simplegui
import random

def draw_handler(canvas):
    x=300 #Should be the center; this is the center of 600x600
    y=300
    for i in range(1000):
        direction=random.randint(1,4) #1=up,2=left,3=down,4=right
        if (direction==1):
            canvas.draw_line([x,y],[x,y-3],3,"Black")
            y=y-3
        if (direction==2):
            canvas.draw_line([x,y],[x-3,y],3,"Black")
            x=x-3
        if (direction==3):
            canvas.draw_line([x,y],[x,y+3],3,"Black")
            y=y+3
        if (direction==4):
            canvas.draw_line([x,y],[x+3,y],3,"Black")
            x=x+3


frame = simplegui.create_frame('Testing', 600, 600)
frame.set_canvas_background("White")
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.start()
```

Comment: Never used `simplegui` but I would guess the `draw_handler` gets called whenever the window needs to be refreshed (hidden, shown, maximized, etc.) See if you can draw the lines to an off-screen buffer and just copy that whenever the window needs a refresh.

Comment: Side note: parentheses are not needed for the `if` conditions in Python: `if direction == 1:`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The [drawing handler function](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#set_draw_handler) is called 60 times by second, to *redraw completely the canvas*.
I precise that on the documentation of [SimpleGUICS2Pygame](https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpleguics2pygame/frame.html#SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame.frame.Frame.set_draw_handler) that reimplements SimpleGUI in the standard Python implementation.

You need to accumulate the path, adding one point at each call of the drawing handler function, and then draw all the path. See this [example](https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user306_D2FYnH7Yuwl34Lf.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Random path
"""
import random

try:
    import simplegui
except ImportError:
    # SimpleGUICS2Pygame: https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/
    import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui


def main():
    width = 600
    height = 600

    points = [(width // 2, height // 2)]

    def draw_handler(canvas):
        last_x, last_y = points[-1]
        new_x = last_x
        new_y = last_y
        direction = random.choice((-1, 1))
        if random.randrange(2) == 0:
            new_y += direction * 3
        else:
            new_x += direction * 3

        points.append((new_x, new_y))

        a = points[0]
        for b in points[1:]:
            canvas.draw_line(a, b, 1, 'Black')
            a = b

    frame = simplegui.create_frame('Random path', width, height)
    frame.set_canvas_background('White')
    frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
    frame.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```